# R tidyr::unite How to prevent blank columns from being deleted?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to create a .txt file to submit a National Death Index (NDI) query (hence the txt format). Among other data, one needs to submit last and first name. The first name should be truncated to 20 characters and the first name should be truncated to 15 characters.

Please note I am first saving the query as a .csv and then saving the .csv as .txt from Excel (not R)

I am doing something very inefficient but this is not the part giving me trouble.

```
### Last name

column_1 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 1, 1)
column_2 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 2, 2)
column_3 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 3, 3)
column_4 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 4, 4)
column_5 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 5, 5)
column_6 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 6, 6)
column_7 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 7, 7)
column_8 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 8, 8)
column_9 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 9, 9)
column_10 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 10, 10)
column_11 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 11, 11)
column_12 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 12, 12)
column_13 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 13, 13)
column_14 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 14, 14)
column_15 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 15, 15)
column_16 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 16, 16)
column_17 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 17, 17)
column_18 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 18, 18)
column_19 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 19, 19)
column_20 <- substring(cases_alive$last, 20, 20) 

### First name

column_21 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 1, 1)
column_22 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 2, 2)
column_23 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 3, 3)
column_24 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 4, 4)
column_25 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 5, 5)
column_26 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 6, 6)
column_27 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 7, 7)
column_28 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 8, 8)
column_29 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 9, 9)
column_30 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 10, 10)
column_31 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 11, 11)
column_32 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 12, 12)
column_33 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 13, 13)
column_34 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 14, 14)
column_35 <- substring(cases_alive$first, 15, 15)

### Create NDI data frame 

ndi <- data.frame(column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6, column_7, column_8, column_9, column_10, ### Last name
                  column_11, column_12, column_13, column_14, ### Last name
                  column_15, column_16, column_17, column_18, column_19, column_20, ### Last name
                  column_21, column_22, column_23, column_24, column_25, column_26, column_27, column_28, # First name
                  column_29, column_31, column_32, column_33, column_34, column_35) # First name
```

Now I want to merging:

```
ndi <- tidyr::unite(ndi, col, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6, column_7, column_8, column_9, column_10, 
                    column_11, column_12, column_13, column_14, 
                    column_15, column_16, column_17, column_18, column_19,column_20, 
                    column_21, column_22, column_23, column_24, column_25, column_26, column_27, column_28,
                    column_29, column_31, column_32, column_33, column_34, column_35, sep = "", na.rm = FALSE)
```

***The problem***: The blank "columns" are being removed. For example, if someone's last name has 5 characters ("smith") and their first name has 4 characters ("john") the output is "smithjohn" and not "smith          john           ". In other words, the blank spaces are being lost.

Sorry for the long disorganized question. I am clearly a newbie at coding. Thanks much.

Comment: You should just do `paste(substr(cases_alive$last, 1, 20), substr(cases_alive$first, 1, 15))`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still "loose" the blank spaces. For this query, we need to preserve the blank saves.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `sprintf` ?

```
ndi <- data.frame(col = sprintf('%20s %15s',cases_alive$last, cases_alive$first))
```

Comment: Thanks much. The issue is the formatting is lost. It becomes center justified.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and show expected output for it? Example dataframe could be as simple as `cases_alive <- data.frame(first = c('first1', 'first2'), last = c('last1', 'last2'))` and maybe show expected output for the data.